# custom kernel and firmware loading

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, firmware

After I have compiled my kernel, and when I type `make modules_install`, not only are the modules copied into `/lib/modules/` but also firmware is copied into `/lib/firmware/`. The following is the end of the output after typing `make modules_install`:

```
MKDIR   /lib/firmware/radeon
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R100_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R200_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R300_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R420_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RS690_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RS600_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R520_cp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R600_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/R600_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV610_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV630_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV620_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV635_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV670_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RS780_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV770_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV730_me.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/radeon/RV710_me.bin
```

As it happens, I need firmware for my ATI radeon graphic card. But I already had firmware in `/lib/firmware/` and I did not want that firmware be build.  I have  selected following options in my kernel:

```
[*] Select only drivers that don't need compile-time external firmware
[*] Prevent firmware from being built
```

So why is firmware being build anyway?

And also, how do I find out which one of these firwares my card needs? I can see following message in my `dmesg`, but that does not tell me which file was loaded:

```
[drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV620 0x1002:0x95CF 0x1002:0x2143).
[drm] Loading RV620 Microcode
```

Is there some way to list loaded firmwares, similarly as I would list loaded modules (`lsmod`)

## CLARIFICATION:

To sum up my question: 
I have `ATI RV620 (FirePro 2260)` graphics  card and I am using kernel `3.12.20`. How can I find out exactly which firmware files my card needs to load?

```
# lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 [FirePro 2260]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following commands:

```
modinfo -F firmware `lsmod | tail -n +2 | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
```

or

```
lsmod | tail -n +2 | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs modinfo -F firmware
```

Comment: neither command prints anything

Comment: Then it means there is no firmware loaded. I tested on my system and it shows some loaded firmware: rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw
rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw
rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw
rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw

Comment: but according to `dmesg`, the firmware `RV620` has been loaded during boot.

Comment: I have tested on a stock kernel not a custom compiled one.